# How to get app download link from Diawi on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, download, diawi

How can i get the downloadable link of uploaded apps in laravel? I want to store the links in mysql. I have used curl to upload apps. Here is my code!

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"); 
    $postfields = array(
        "token"             => 'IXWEsIpQBRUM4gSDu6f9aLB7W2AEPlsGb2kAJRVmRw',
        "file"              => new \CurlFile( $filename ),
        "find_by_udid"      => 0,
        "wall_of_apps"      => 1
        // "callback_email"    => ''
        );
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36'
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    curl_exec($ch);

    if(!curl_errno($ch))
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);         
        if ($info['http_code'] == 200)
            $curl_error = "File uploaded successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
else
{
    $curl_error = "Please select the file";
}
echo $curl_error;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, when your upload succeeds Diawi returns you a Job ID, by which you can create a tracker link and make a GET request on it. There in response you can get the download link (or error message if the file failed Diawi's checks.. wrong format?)

The link format is like

```
 https://upload.diawi.com/status?token={TOKEN}&job={JOB_ID}
```

Try this

```
    $headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
    $postfields = array(
        "token"             => 'IXWEsIpQBRUM4gSDu6f9aLB7W2AEPlsGb2kAJRVmRw',
        "file"              => new \CurlFile( $filename ),
        "find_by_udid"      => 0,
        "wall_of_apps"      => 1,
        //"callback_email"    => ''
        );
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        //CURLOPT_HEADER => true, <-- don't need this otherwise would mess the response body
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 // we need to collect the diawi's json response
    ); // cURL options
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $op = curl_exec($ch); //<-- $op contains the job details if success

    if(!curl_errno($ch))
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        if ($info['http_code'] == 200){
            $curl_error = "File uploaded successfully"; //<-- not really you can't be sure unless you check the tracker link response

            $job_details = json_decode($op); //the response is in json format
            $job_id = $job_details->job;

            //THE TRACKER LINK FORMAT
            //https://upload.diawi.com/status?token={TOKEN}&job={JOB_ID}

            $status_link = 'https://upload.diawi.com/status?token=IXWEsIpQBRUM4gSDu6f9aLB7W2AEPlsGb2kAJRVmRw&job='.$job_id;

            $ch2 = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $status_link);
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $op2 = curl_exec($ch2);

            $upload_response = json_decode($op2);
            if($upload_response->status == 2000){
                echo '<br>File uploaded successfully : download link ' . $upload_response->link;
            }
            curl_close($ch2);

        }

    }
    else
    {
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

PS: It's always better to mask your API keys when posting them on Q/A platforms